# what is different between real mouse click and custom javascript click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

so I'm trying simulate real mouse click, but nothing goes well... i tried lot of ways but still can't simulate it. 
please tell me is possible simulate real mouse click with javascript?
if yes give me some hints.

```
    function click(x,y){
        var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
        var el = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
        ev.initMouseEvent(
            "click",
            true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
            window, null,
            x, y, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
            false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
            0 /*left*/, null
        );
        el.dispatchEvent(ev);
    }

click(100,100);
```

this is my last try but it is not same as real click.
i saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609679/simulate-real-mouse-click) topic on stackoverflow which have same idea but it is old and if is some new way to do this kind of stuff please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-using-javascript

Comment: i tested it and it does not works for me, does it depends browser type? and version? i'm testing on chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 m